# Cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating my Android app project from `GCM` to `FCM`. For this I use Firebase assistant tool in Android Studio and followed instructions from Google developer guide. Everything went fine and changed my app code for `FCM` according to Assistant tool. Now, its time to run and test app. And I got following strange error :

> cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

I am getting this error where I am using google maps and trying to set marker position.
Here's my app level gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kennyc1012/maven' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        msapp {
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Default
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    //jar files
    implementation files('libs/classes.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    //google repos
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'


    //square lib
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'

    //text manupulation
    implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'

    //permission library.
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you solved your issuie ?

Comment: you can try invalidating IDE cache and restart. The menu is under file. In case something was not correctly updated and old stuffs cached

Answer (score 7):

To resolve your problem, first i will ask you to always use specified and updated version.
    1. Replace + with specific version here : `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'`
    2. Try to use same version for now to run the apk,

```
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  targetSdkVersion 27
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

3. Use an updated version of google play service

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.3'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered same issue after migrating **AndroidX** and
Solved by changing version of **gms library** for **maps and location** as below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please Change your Firebase and Google Library to same version .
For an Example like this

```
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
        //your firebase lib version to the same version 
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases is required to upgrade play-services and firebase version dependencies, maybe the last one available if you are using **androidx** but if not:

Try to check it out the [maven_repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services/12.0.1) and choose some version that helps you fix it. For example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

the chosen version is the last one before version 17 due to the v17.0.0 require androidx (in play-service)

Don't forget to update your google-service in your build.gradle(project)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [Latest SDK versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
```

And according to official documentation regarding on to [set up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), please change the follwing lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
```

to

```
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0' //Commented line
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

Please also be sure to have:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

In your top level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just update versions of libraries "......gms:play-services....." to the latest
To check the latest versions, refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)