# How to use Firebase in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am getting mad from gradle issues after adding Firebase to my app,
I get the error:
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

I am using android location and url stringRequest, until then it worked well, then I have added Firebase to the gradle (I have registered in the Firebase website and added the generated google-services.json)

I checked for alot of answeres that didnt help, I have updated gradle to 3.4.2 still not working

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mapwithmarker"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        //maven {
         //   url "https://maven.google.com"
        //}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

any help please?

Comment: Try to downgrade the gradle version to 3.2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251502/cannot-access-zzbfm-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbfm-not-fou)

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani this was my gradle before the change. same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by:
...

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

thanks

Comment: I am glade that you fixed the problem

Comment: btw, no need to comment the last line, it works only with it, the only change needed is to go back to firebase version 12.0.1 !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned  from [official docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup),

“ Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.”

you should not use combined play services library. Instead try using specific libraries you need and try updating the specific library to 17.0.0

Comment: I toke this line from firbase guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the compatible versions of your firebase and play-services libs. the version should be released at the same time.

**In this case**

Change this line :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

With this one :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.1'
```

Comment: this creates this error:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.1

Comment: Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**Firebase documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0).

Or follow this:

Tools -> Firebase -> Choose your library -> Follow instructions

[image]
[image]
[image]